# Как отобразить анимацию (Animated Drawable) на SurfaceView?

Tags: android, canvas, glsurfaceview, android-drawable, android-animation

Возможно ли как нибуть запустить анимацию через поток рисования в SurfaceView?
Весь день просидел в поисках решения и ничего толкового не нашел. Буду благодарен, если кто нибудь поделиться или посоветует что то. Спасибо.

Comment: вы можете самостоятельно покадрово рисовать на canvas то, что нужно анимировать. Готовую анимацию, мне кажется, вряд ли

Comment: А можете уточнить как, пожалуйста. Я начинающий в андроид разработке) Спасибо)

Comment: Уточню, как только вы расскажете, какую анимацию вы хоитите сделать